# qual a intenção do foreach?

Tags: c#

```
    private List<Evento> ListaDeEventos = new List<Evento>();//cria a lista

    public void AddEvento(Evento e)//adiciona na lista
    {
        this.ListaDeEventos.Add(e);
    }

    public void CadastrarEvento()//adiciona valor nas variaveis
    {
        Evento evento = new Evento();
        Console.WriteLine("Diga o nome do evento: ");
        evento.nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Diga o endereço do evento: ");
        evento.endereco = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Diga a categoria do evento: ");
        evento.categoria = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Descreva brevemente o evento: ");
        evento.descricao = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Informe a data e hora do evento (Ex.: 01/01/2016 12:00:00): ");
        evento.horario = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
        this.AddEvento(evento);

    }
    public void DisplayEventos() //metodo para mostrar o conteudo dos eventos
    {
        foreach (Evento e in this.ListaDeEventos)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Te aconselho dar uma lida no [manual de como não fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/18246). E tente ser mais específico. O que esse método deveria fazer? Qual é o problema? Qual a intenção do foreach?

Comment: @jbueno desculpe, a ansiedade bateu mais forte e sou novo aqui. Peço perdão.

Comment: Só tô te dando dicas. De qualquer forma, você pode [edit] sua questão a qualquer momento para melhorá-la.

Answer (score 2):

Suponho que a sua pergunta seja como ***iterar*** pelo laço **foreach** para que o seu método:

```
    public void DisplayEventos() { ... }
```

Exiba as informações dos eventos, que foram previamente armazenadas na lista de eventos:

```
    private List<Evento> ListaDeEventos = new List<Evento>();
```

O seu método pode ser assim:

```
   public void DisplayEventos() //metodo para mostrar o conteudo dos eventos
    {
        foreach (Evento e in ListaDeEventos)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEvento: {0}", e.Nome);
            Console.Write("\nEndereço: {0}", e.Endereco);
            Console.Write("\nCategoria: {0}", e.Categoria);
            Console.Write("\nDescrição: {0}", e.Descricao);
            Console.Write("\nHorário: {0}", e.Horario);
        }
    }
```

**iterar**

**1.** *t.d.* fazer ou dizer novamente; repetir, reiterar
 **2.** *t.d.* álg fazer uso da ***iteração*** em

**ETIMOLOGIA**

- 'recomeçar, renovar, repetir'

**SINÔNIMOS/VARIANTES**

- ver sinonímia de ***repetir***

Fonte: Dicionário Apple 2.2.1 (178)